# How to get the variable associated with an NET-SNMP registered callback

Tags: c, callback, snmp, net-snmp

I've been following the NET-SNMP Tutorial found [here](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_Subagent).

**Set-Up:**

In the example there is this line of code.

```
 netsnmp_register_long_instance("nstAgentSubagentObject",
                              nstAgentSubagentObject_oid,
                              OID_LENGTH(nstAgentSubagentObject_oid),
                              &nstAgentSubagentObject, NULL);
```

After doing some investigating I found that the `NULL` is actually a callback pointer of this signature.

```
int CallBackFunction(netsnmp_mib_handler*handler, netsnmp_handler_registration*reginfo, 
netsnmp_agent_request_info*reqinfo, netsnmp_request_info*requests)
```

So I can rewrite the previous line of code like this,

```
netsnmp_register_long_instance("nstAgentSubagentObject",
                              nstAgentSubagentObject_oid,
                              OID_LENGTH(nstAgentSubagentObject_oid),
                              &nstAgentSubagentObject, &CallBackFunction);
```

And every time I use the `snmpget` command on one of my variables the callback function `CallBackFunction` is called. Which is great but I can't find a way to get to the pointer of the value registered with the callback AKA `&nstAgentSubagentObject`.

I've looked through the datatypes of 4 parameters and can't figure out what I'm missing.

**Question:**

Is there a way to get to the `&nstAgentSubagentObject` pointer that was registered with the callback function?

Is there a better way to associate these callbacks? I found some documentation on net-snmp's generic callback functionality [here](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/dev/agent/group__callback.html) but if I could just get the pointer with what I have now I'd be all set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
long nstAgentSubagentObject;
size_t long_size = sizeof(long);

int handle_nstAgentSubagentObject(netsnmp_mib_handler *handler, netsnmp_handler_registration *reginfo, netsnmp_agent_request_info *reqinfo, netsnmp_request_info *requests)
{
    printf("handle_nstAgentSubagentObject\n");    

    switch(reqinfo->mode) {
        case MODE_GET:
            nstAgentSubagentObject = 100500;
            snmp_set_var_typed_value(requests->requestvb, ASN_INTEGER,
                                         &nstAgentSubagentObject,
                                         long_size);
            break;
        default:
            snmp_log(LOG_ERR, "unknown mode (%d) in handle_totalClients\n", reqinfo->mode );
            return SNMP_ERR_GENERR;
    }
    return SNMP_ERR_NOERROR;
}
```

May will be usefull for someone

Counter64 usage (subagent agentx):

```
struct counter64 createdFlowsAll;
size_t counter64_size = sizeof(struct counter64); // sizeof(U64);

netsnmp_register_instance (
        netsnmp_create_handler_registration("createdFlowsAll", handle_createdFlowsAll, createdFlowsAll_oid, OID_LENGTH(createdFlowsAll_oid), HANDLER_CAN_RONLY
    ));

int handle_createdFlowsAll(netsnmp_mib_handler *handler, netsnmp_handler_registration *reginfo, netsnmp_agent_request_info *reqinfo, netsnmp_request_info *requests)
{
    size_t i;
    u_long createdFlowsAll_t;

    switch(reqinfo->mode) {
        case MODE_GET:
            createdFlowsAll_t = 100500;

            // createdFlowsAll.high = createdFlowsAll_t & 0xffffffff00000000ULL;
            // createdFlowsAll.low = createdFlowsAll_t & 0x00000000ffffffffULL;

            createdFlowsAll.high = createdFlowsAll_t >> 32;
            createdFlowsAll.low = createdFlowsAll_t & 0xffffffff;

            snmp_set_var_typed_value(requests->requestvb, ASN_COUNTER64,
                                     &createdFlowsAll,
                                     counter64_size);
            break;
        default:
            snmp_log(LOG_ERR, "unknown mode (%d) in handle_createdFlowsAll\n", reqinfo->mode );
            return SNMP_ERR_GENERR;
    }
    return SNMP_ERR_NOERROR;
}
```